# Как сделать, чтобы русский язык отображался корректно

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include 
<locale.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
char surName[100];
cout<<"Введите Фамилию и Имя\n";
cin.getline(surName, 516) >>surName;//ввод фамилии и имени

char groupName[100];
cout << "Введите группу\n";
cin.getline(groupName, 516) >> groupName;//ввод группы

cout << "Студент" << ":" << surName<<" " << "Группа" << ":" << groupName<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

При добавлении setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); становится нормальным текст написанный в " ", но ломается введённый, при удалении setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); наблюдается обратная картина

Answer (score 0):

Что за новая кодировка RUS?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-170

Русские кодировки `ru-RU.CP1251` или `ru-RU.UTF-8`

Аналогично для Windows:

SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

> становится нормальным текст написанный в " ", но ломается введённый

А какая у тебя кодировка самого файла *.c ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий вариант (Лучше подключать в самом начале функции main):

```
system("chcp 1251");
system("cls");
```

После выполнения первой строчки в консоль будет выведено: "Текущая кодовая страница: 1251".

Второй строчкой очищаем консоль (чтоб избавиться от той фразы).

Ну и для справочки: [Windows-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251#:%7E:text=Windows-1251%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8,%C2%AB%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%C2%BB%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20Microsoft)